# QTableView to display only leaves of a tree model implemented with QAbstractItemModel

Tags: c++, qt, tree, model-view

Assume I have a tree structure (tree leaves in **bold**, sorry for the dots):

---

- A
- - **A1**
- - **A2**
- B
- - B1
- - - **B11**
- - **B2**
- **C**

---

stored in a QAbstractItemModel (with set parent/child relations).

How to display only the tree leaves in a QTableView?

Basic idea was to implement a QSortFilterProxyModel. Intuition suggested there would be a way to iterate through the tree and return a valid index if the item is a leaf, or QModelIndex() if not.

```
// QAbstractItemModel *model;
m_leavesModel.setSourceModel(model); // QSortFilterProxyModel m_leavesModel;
m_leavesTableView->setModel(&m_leavesModel);
```

At the moment I can only display "first level" items - A, B and C, just below the root.

Comment: How do you know which node to display? What is the criterion?

Comment: Display only nodes with no child nodes (e.g. *node->isLeaf() == true* or *node->childCount() == 0*), so I guess it could be broadened up to "display a *list* of only the nodes of the tree, which meet an arbitrary condition".

Comment: Maybe solution for this problem in this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588408/how-to-display-sub-rows-of-qabstractitemmodel-in-qtableview?lq=1